# NullPointerException on WinForms Application.Exit()

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, frameworks

First of all; I do know what a NullPointerException is. I am well aware of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

In my WinForms application I am getting a NullReferenceException at the Application.Exit call with the following Stacktrace:

> System.NullReferenceException occured.   HResult=0x80004003   Message
>   = The Object-Reference was not set to an instance of the object   Source = Microsoft.VisualBasic   StackMonitoring:     at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.MainFormLoadingDone(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)    at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e)    at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr
>   hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Originally the message was german due my VS17 beeing german, which I will definitly change to english later on. I translated the few german parts to english.

Also my VS17 shows me [image: Screenshot of Visual Studio] where it says

> Application is on Hold
>   Your application was paused, but there is no code to show, because all threads executed external code (usually system- or frameworkcode).

After some research I found out, that most times the error occured on Form Closing and Form Closed events. Since I have not created any closing events myself I do not think that I will find my solution on those.

Calling Environment.Exit(1) instead of Application.Exit() does work, but since this one basicly just kills the process I would like to not use it.

Do you guys have any ideas where to look for the error?

---

Exception was probably due to the following:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If Environment.GetCommandLineArgs.Contains("Confirmation") Then
       Dim a As New confirmationForm
       a.ShowDialog()
       Application.Exit()
    End If
End Sub
```

There was also an `Application.Exit()` Call on `a.Button1_Press()` event. This probably caused the exception. Will update as soon as I have fixed it.

Solution can be found in the answer + comments

Comment: It appears to happen in/after a `Form.Load` event. Do you call `Application.Exit()` at application startup/when you open some new form?

Comment: Good point. Somehow I actually do call it on a formload event. If the application starts with a parameter it opens the mainform and then on formload opens a childform that will call Application.Exit() on a button press. If you know more for that case let me know. I will now try to debug inside my parents form load event. First I will move my form Load code to open the child form to the form shown event

Comment: But does _**the `Load` event itself**_ call `Application.Exit()`, or is it only called if you _press a button_? If the latter then it's not relevant.

Comment: I'll say it does, since the child is called using Form.ShowDialog() it will wait for that dialog. If I call Application.Exit() inside that Dialog-Form it will call the Application.Exit() inside the Load event. I will update my question with the relevant code.

Comment: Actually it's even worse. Some stupid coding mistake I did there! I am calling Form.ShowDialog() and on the next line Application.Exit(). Also I am calling Application.Exit() inside that Dialog-Form which will most likely cause the exception.

Comment: It will not literally call `Application.Exit()` _**in the event**_, but since you use `ShowDialog()` it will at least be called before the event is finished, so yeah it is causing the problem.

Comment: Updated question. Problem is solved. Thank you for your massive help, basicly I was lost before. Feel free to post an answer on the question for the additional rep if you want to. A (probably) last question; Would you say calling the lines in the question at the Form.Shown() event is fine? Where would you put those lines and why?

Comment: I guess it's fine. Though I prefer the `Startup` event since that is raised before any form is shown (see answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find yourself needing to open another form than the main one I'd rather utilize the application's [**`Startup` event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.startup(v=vs.110).aspx) for that. It is raised before the main form is shown.

Calling `Environment.Exit()` after that is harmless. Just make sure that all ***your*** code has finished executing so it doesn't get interrupted for instance while writing to files.

If you really don't want to call `Environment.Exit()` you can try `Application.Exit()` as well, but I cannot say exactly what will happen if you try to do it in the `Startup` event (i.e. whether it will still attempt to show the main form or not).

```
Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
    If Environment.GetCommandLineArgs.Contains("Confirmation") Then
        Dim a As New confirmationForm
        a.ShowDialog()
        Environment.Exit(0) '0 = Terminated with no error (success).
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

It turns out you can actually stop the loading of the main form by setting `e.Cancel = True` in the `Startup` event, so that's a better alternative to `Environment.Exit()`.

```
If Environment.GetCommandLineArgs.Contains("Confirmation") Then
    Dim a As New confirmationForm
    a.ShowDialog()
    e.Cancel = True 'Do not show the main form.
End If
```

Comment: Just for the record; I did know that 1 in `Environment.Exit()` stands for an error. I put it in there since it was only used as a workaround for an error.  Your code seems nice. I am wondering where exactly to put that sub. Putting it into the mainforms class seems wrong. Perfect would be to achieve an If/Else before any form is created. I know Visual studio generates code "application.run(new mainform())" when you set a startform. But I don't think Visual Studio wants me to edit those generated classes.

Comment: @Luke : Check the [**linked documentation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.startup(v=vs.110).aspx), it describes how you access the event (see Remarks).

Comment: My bad. Great addition to the answers you posted in the comments earlier. Thank you!

Comment: @Luke : No problem, glad I could help! -- Make sure to check out my edit as well.